# Can we burninate [prompt]?

Tags: discussion, burnination-request

I don't see much point of the [prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/prompt) tag, and it only has ~100 questions tagged with it.

Shall we burninate it?

*P.S. Let's also nuke [lag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lag)*

Comment: There are no questions with [tag:lag] as a tag.

Comment: @KazWolfe - right, so there should no problem nuking it, no?

Comment: It would be better to keep this and make [tag:PS1] a synonym of this.

Comment: @AndroidDev It needs no manual intervention - it will auto nuke itself eventually if it's not in use and has no tag wiki.  At least, if I remember right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say no here.

[The prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt) is a specific (and independent) aspect of a terminal system. While prompt-related questions *can* live under [command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command-line), so could [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash).

They seem distinct enough to be different, so they seem okay to stay. However, [prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/prompt) *should* be edited to reflect this difference and make it clear what this question is to be used for (namely, questions about the ready-state of any given command line).